# запрос по частичному совпадению данных

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток

Допустим в табличке есть столбик datatime (формат 0000-00-00 00:00:00). Подскажите, можно ли в запросе сделать:

```
WHERE `datatime`>'2012-05-** **:**:**' ? // т.е. дата больше 2012-05
```

p.s. то есть, есть равно/неравно/больше/меньше. интересует можно ли производить запрос по частичному совпадению данных?

Comment: А чем не подходит?

    WHERE `datatime`>'2012-05-01 00:00:00'

или, то-же самое:

    WHERE `datatime`>'2012-05-01'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE `datatime` > '2012-05-10 %'
```